# How can I switch solar panels on and off with a microcontroller?

Tags: mosfet, battery-charging, solar-cell, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

I have built a li-ion 18650 7S pack as my solar backup.  It is being charged by 3*250W solar panels in series (about 105V 8A.)

My charger doesn't have an option to monitor individual cell voltages. It just charges the battery pack to the given voltage (4.2V*7 = 29.4V.)

I have a BMS monitoring my pack and if a cell goes above 4.2V it generates a signal which I monitor using an ESP32.

What I want to do is turn off solar side if cell goes above 4.2V with that signal.

Can Mosfet do this job or is there a better way to achieve this?

**Note: The BMS has overvoltage cutoff but if I connect the solar charger through the BMS, it cuts off the battery power to the controller while PV side is on. The controller manual clearly say that cut PV before battery.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for would ideally be handled by a properly implemented charger and balancing BMS.

However, a somewhat informal but entirely doable way of shutting down solar input is to use a suitable rated MOSFET to **short circuit** the solar array - or a portion of it. The MOSFET MUST be either fully on or fully off.
The solar array is not harmed by short circuiting and dissipates minimal energy.

Power dissipation = I^2R. At 8A and say a 10 milliOhm MOSFET power in the FET
= 64 x 0.010 = 0.64 Watt.
10 milliohm Rdson MOSFETS are common and cheap and even lower or much lower Rdson devices are readily available. At that power dissipation heatsinking is trivially easy.

A relay could be used for the same purpose. However, opening a 100V 8A DC contact requires switches designed for the task. At those power levels the system is potentially lethal - both due to the voltage alone and also due to the arc potential.

Unless there was a good reason to run the panels in series at 100V+ I'd favour operating them in parallel at 35V.

**Related:**

Using 3 x 35V panels in series to charge a 29.4V max 7S battery pack sounds very strange UNLESS you have an MPPT controller.  IF you have an MPPT controller that's (potentially) fine.

A BMS usually both detects cell overvoltage AND drains current from the charging source to prevent cell overcharging. As long as the battery is reasonably well balanced a balancing BMS will be able to handle the current needed to maintain balance.

Comment: Hmm - are there induction or resistive-region issues with this solution? The classic failure of e.g. motor driver schemes is that they work in the static analysis and then blow up during switching. Perhaps put a standard 100V bulb in there as a dump resistor.

Comment: @pjc50 Right, the MOSFET might absorb significant energy during the switching. I'm not sure how an extra resistor would help with that. Maybe you could add a snubber network so that the current through the MOSFET won't rise much until the MOSFET is fully on and the voltage across it won't rise much until it's fully off.

Comment: IF you can keep away from arc formation then shorting/opening PV panels is fairly benign. There "should be" minimal inductance. If you do have inductance you need to snub the worst case energy spike. [I can "arc weld" (very carefully) using a single 35V, 300W panel! That rather amazed me - drawing and holding an arc with suitably tiny electrodes (or wire ends) is a warning of what can happen. A friend of a friend stupidly pulled open a connector on a 400V ish string on a sunny day. He was hospitalised.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Out of curiosity, what was his injury?

Comment: yes charger controller is a MPPT one.  when i looking through the solutions, i found that DC-DC Solid state relays available. can this do the job?

Comment: It 'should be' a relatively tame MOSFET task. You should be able to switch it in say 10-100 uS with ease. Say you did it in 1 ms. Energy = Voc x Isc /2 x t  = 100 x 8 /2 * 0.001 = 0.4 J = 0.4 Watt.second. You can get for $4.19/1 this 200V  100A 10 mOhm [SUG9009](http://www.vishay.com/docs/75009/sug90090e.pdf) with Rthja pf 40C/W - so you could run it wityh no heatsink (not that I'd recommend it). It has a 0.5J one time avalanche capability -  and actual in transition should be MUCH less than that.

Comment: @user253751 Details unknown - burns. It was recounted to me more as a cautionary tale. He was somewhat drunk and decided to disconnect the string for some reason :-(. You can easily die doing that. Easily. [It is in fact a true story - not just the sort of 'internet makeup' one encounters :-) :-(].

Comment: @GihanLasita A MOSFEt is just a portion of a DIY SSR - if the SSR is properly rated then yes. BUT if that was my system I would see if I could make the BMS and charger cooperate.

Comment: problem seems to be BMS can do about 60mA balancing.  one time i had a two loose fuses  and that pack reached 4.2v quickly than other 6packs and bms triggered the overcharging cutoff.